# Are Ricola drops pareve?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, food, meat-and-milk, dairy

Are [Ricola drops](https://www.ricola.com/en-us/products/all-products) [certified by Rabbi A. Yafe Schlesinger](https://www.kashrut.com/articles/medicine_list/Ricola.pdf) considered pareve?

Comment: https://app.iskosher.com/product/ricola/ricola_honey_sage-2518123.html

Comment: Shouldn't this question be directed to Rabbi Schlesinger?

Comment: I would expect they are. Rabbi S is one of the biggest poskim today. And has very likely written more than anyone else. If milky it would be stated.

Comment: This app lists one of the drop types certified by Rabbi Schlesinger as parve, but not sure how their source kosher4u.eu determined it - https://app.iskosher.com/product/ricola_ch/ricola_mountain_herbs_cought__throat_drops_-_sugar_free-1015773.html